# Increase Eclipse debugger toString buffer size

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I commonly have fairly large toString() representations of data structures that I need to debug. But, when I highlight them in the Eclipse debugger they get truncated to 10000 chars with a "..." termination.

How do I change the limit? Preferably to unlimited.

Comment: You can print the whole object to stdout and it won't get truncated.

Comment: But then I have to modify the code. I think Eclipse should be smarter than that.

Comment: No, it's not perfect, but you don't have to modify the code. You can type `System.out.println(foo)` into the Display pane and execute that code.

Comment: Nice, not what I wanted but I think that is very valuable. I you put it in an answer I can give you some rep.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing complete strings while debugging in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873949/viewing-complete-strings-while-debugging-in-eclipse) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3199611/139010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered [Viewing complete strings while debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873949) by Eugene Kuleshov but it is not the selected answer so I am listing what I believe is the correct answer here.

From the Debug Perspective right click on the text pane in the Variables tab and select "Mac Length" Set the value to 0 for unlimited or whichever other number you prefer.

Comment: That solution does not work with Eclipse PDT PHP debugging, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting up a Detail Formatter for your class (open Preferences and search for "detail")? Using a custom formatter might bypass the truncation.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP Xdebug debugging with Eclipse PDT, two settings have to be configured:

- *Window* > *Preferences* > *PHP* > *Debug* > *Debuggers* > select *Xdebug* > Configure > under *General Settings* > *Max data*: provide a sufficiently large value, e.g. `1000000`. > *Apply and Close* > *Apply and Close*.[image: Screenshot showing the windows towards setting Eclipse Xdebug's max data setting]
- In the *Variables* debugger view, right click the lower "variable value" area. From the pop-up, select *Max Length...*. In the *Configure Details Pane* modal, provide the value `0`.[image: Screenshot showing the popup for opening the Max Length modal]
  [image: Screenshot showing the Max Length modal]

Now Eclipse needs to be restarted for these settings to take effect.