# The value of strings doesn't appear in eclipse mars CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-mars

Why does the value of `strings` in Eclipse Mars CDT not appear in the expression or `variables` windows?
It appears `{...}` but i want to see the value itself under the value tab.

How can i do this?

Comment: it's probably truncated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873949/viewing-complete-strings-while-debugging-in-eclipse

Comment: i cant see the max length or the change value options when i right click on the value section.

Answer (score 6):

What is going on here is CDT is showing the information that GDB is providing to it.

For a trivial program, with the debugger stopped on the line with return 0;

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string mystring = "my string here";
    return 0;
}
```

this is what I see in the CDT variable view:

[image: cdt view of variable]

which matches what I see in GDB:

```
(gdb) p mystring 
$1 = {static npos = <optimised out>, 
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    _M_p = 0x602028 "my string here"}}
```

### Pretty Printing C++

However, what I suspect you want is the pretty printers for libstdc++ which makes the variables view look like this:

[image: string pretty printed]

Create a ~/.gdbinit file with the following contents (updating the path for your machine)

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gcc-4.8/python/')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

Then point your launch configuration at that gdbinit file and start debugging.

- GDB wiki entry on the subject:
  https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport
- GCC manual entry:
  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html

Comment: how to make this work with Eclipse CDT running in Windows? (compiler is mingw)

Comment: @jose.diego It should work the same as in Windows, assuming that you are using a gdb with python enabled (afaik mingw and msys2 both enable by default), you may have to update the path to the correct path. If that does not work, please post a new answer showing the error you get with the eclipse-cdt tag and we can work on it there.

Comment: it looks like I have to do this, instead:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1083556&goto=1751218&

there are no python binaries in my mingw distro, so I gonna try to use one of my standalone python versions I have here, instead