# Debugging data structures with eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, data-structures

I wonder if there is a plugin or a recommended way for eclipse to see only interesting contents of common data structures when debugging. For example when debugging a string, I would like to see just the string value not the entire data structure, similarly when debugging a vector array I am interested in to see just the members and size, not the underlying complicated members.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The value of strings doesn't appear in eclipse mars CDT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411117/the-value-of-strings-doesnt-appear-in-eclipse-mars-cdt)

Comment: I am getting following error
  File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'

Comment: ask a new question and I will be glad to try to answer it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482030/python-pretty-printer-for-debugging-stdlib-variables-wont-work

Comment: Excellent, now that you have reposted that as its own question, with the GDB tag, hopefully the right people will see it.

Answer (score 2):

You can put some expressions in the [expression view](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fexpressions%2Fref-expressions_view.htm) of Eclipse and show only what you need .

[image: Expression View]

Comment: is it possible for you to give a sample use incase of string forexample?