# ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx' when starting Eclipse debugger

Tags: linux, eclipse, gcc, gdb, eclipse-cdt

When I run Eclipse CDT debugger in Linux, I see the following error in GDB console:

```
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
```

What does it mean, can I fix it, and should I fix it?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33482030/2796832

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in more recent versions of libstdc++6. For now, edit the `libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py` file to make these changes (sample from Ubuntu 14.04):

```
*** libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py.orig 2015-05-14 11:41:01 -0700
--- libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py 2016-01-17 08:00:54 -0800
***************
*** 49,54 ****
      # Compute the ".."s needed to get from libdir to the prefix.
!     backdirs = len (libdir.split (os.sep))
!     if not os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__)).startswith('lib'):
!         backdirs += 1 # multiarch subdir
!     dotdots = ('..' + os.sep) * backdirs

--- 49,51 ----
      # Compute the ".."s needed to get from libdir to the prefix.
!     dotdots = ('..' + os.sep) * len (libdir.split (os.sep))
```