# Can't see std::string values in Eclipse debugger under Windows

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

When I am debugging a simple C++ program under Linux, I can't see the content of variables of `std::string`:

[image]

Simultaneously, I can see these variables if I do `c_str()` with it.

Can I see variables as is?

Comment: You need to dive into `std::string`'s inner class members.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32411117/2796832