# Using Eclipse CDT gui wrapper for gdb to analyze a dump

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I have a crash dump from my c++ application in ubuntu. I am using gdb to analyze the dump.

I can run the following commands:

```
bt
frame #
info args
print *this
```

The output of the `print *this` is not very neat.

I learned that you can use a gui wrapper Eclipse cdt for gdb. I tried finding some information how to do that but couldn't find a very clear answer on how can this be done.

How can I analyze the dump with gdb using eclipse cdt wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I analyze the dump with gdb using eclipse cdt wrapper?

In [Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/neon3) you do a *C/C++ Postmortem Debugger* session.

1. Download/install [Eclipse with C/C++](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/neon3) support and run it.
2. From the *Run* menu choose *Debug Configurations...*
3. Double-click on *C/C++ Postmortem Debugger*
4. Fill in the form and press Debug. **NOTE:** You don't need a project, that can be left blank.
5. More info in the [help](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.debug.application.doc/tasks/cdt_t_debug_prog.htm).

[image]

> The output of the print *this is not very neat.

Using Eclipse CDT alone may not change this significantly. You may want STL pretty printing to help support this.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048311/2796832 for instructions on setting that up in CDT.