# StringBuilder - Append method stop working at a certain point

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, stringbuilder, stax

I'm working with a small project, [graphipedia](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXuaLrxP_MAhXHkJAKHaA_AJMQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmirkonasato%2Fgraphipedia&usg=AFQjCNEEMnDPnMHX9SOJuHxROURzAbUZ0Q&sig2=0CBR86BVzh6yJBwCj218Ig&bvm=bv.123325700,d.Y2I) (for importing wikipedia dumps), and i'm using a stax parser, for importing a wikiquote dump.

In some moment of the process, i have read some text characters (between <text> and </text>), and the code does an append method to an StringBuilder variable, but for some reason the append doesn't add a single character to the StringBuilder variable.

Here is the code:

```
package org.graphipedia.dataimport;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

import org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2;

public abstract class SimpleStaxParser {

    private static final String STDIN_FILENAME = "-";
    private static final XMLInputFactory XML_INPUT_FACTORY = XMLInputFactory2.newInstance();

    private final List<String> interestingElements;

    public SimpleStaxParser(List<String> interestingElements) {
        this.interestingElements = interestingElements;
    }

    protected abstract void handleElement(String element, String value);

    public void parse(String fileName) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
        if (STDIN_FILENAME.equals(fileName)) {
            parse(System.in);
        } else {
            parse(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        }
    }

    private void parse(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
        XMLStreamReader reader = XML_INPUT_FACTORY.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        try {
            parseElements(reader);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private void parseElements(XMLStreamReader reader) throws XMLStreamException {
        LinkedList<String> elementStack = new LinkedList<String>();
        StringBuilder textBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            switch (reader.next()) {
            case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT:
                elementStack.push(reader.getName().getLocalPart());
                textBuffer.setLength(0);
                break;
            case XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT:
                String element = elementStack.pop();
                if (isInteresting(element)) {
                    handleElement(element, textBuffer.toString().trim());
                }
                break;
            case XMLEvent.CHARACTERS:
                if (isInteresting(elementStack.peek())) {
                    textBuffer.append(reader.getText());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isInteresting(String element) {
        return interestingElements.contains(element);
    }

}
```

The line that is giving me some trouble is this one:

```
textBuffer.append(reader.getText());
```

In that line, `reader.getText()` returns the following:

```
lo que pasó, pasó por una razón...

'''Neo''': ¿Y qué razón es esa?

'''Smith''': Yo lo maté, señor Anderson, lo vi morir... Con cierta satisfacción, debo decir. Y luego algo pasó. Algo que sabía que era imposible, pero aún así pasó: usted me destruyó, señor Anderson... Después, cuando supe las reglas, entendí lo que debí haber hecho, pero no lo hice. No podía, fui obligado a quedarme, fui obligado a desobedecer... Y ahora aquí estoy por su culpa, señor Anderson. Por su culpa, ya no soy un agente de este sistema. Por su culpa cambié, me desconecté. Un hombre libre por decir algo, como usted, aparentemente libre.

'''Neo''': ¡Felicidades!

'''Smith''': Gracias... Pero, como sabrá, las apariencias engañan, lo cual me regresa a la razón por la que estoy aquí. No estamos aquí por ser libres. Estamos aquí por no ser libres. No hay razón de escapatoria, ni propósitos de negación. Porque, como sabemos, sin propósitos, no existiríamos...

'''Clones''': Propósito fue lo que nos creó... propósito lo que nos conecta, propósito lo que nos impulsa, lo que nos guía, lo que nos controla, es el propósito lo que define, propósito lo que nos une.

'''Smith''': Estamos aquí por culpa suya, señor Anderson. Estamos aquí para quitarle lo que trató de quitarnos a nosotros ¡Propósito!

[[Categoría:Películas]]

[[en:The Matrix (franchise)]]
[[sl:Matrica]]
```

Before the append method is executed, the textBuffer variable has a count value of 30643, a capacity of 64254, and the text to add has a length of 1352.

Data on which the parser is working can be seen at: https://es.wikiquote.org/w/index.php?title=The_Matrix&action=edit (is too big for posting it here)

---

Steps for reproducing this problem:
Get [dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/eswikiquote/20160501/eswikiquote-20160501-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2), download [graphipedia](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXuaLrxP_MAhXHkJAKHaA_AJMQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmirkonasato%2Fgraphipedia&usg=AFQjCNEEMnDPnMHX9SOJuHxROURzAbUZ0Q&sig2=0CBR86BVzh6yJBwCj218Ig&bvm=bv.123325700,d.Y2I), unzip it and built it with maven (`mvn package`), and run `ExtractLinks` from `Eclipse` or similar ide, in order to debug the code properly.

Comment: Sorry, explained it to me myself an deleted my comment,

Comment: Could you post sample data?

Comment: I put a link for the sample data. It was too big for inserting it into my question.

Comment: what are your 'intrestingElements', can I reproduce the error with this single dump?

Comment: I added information for reproduce the problem. The interestingElements are "page", "title" and "text"

Comment: Sorry again, get 404 on link to dump

Comment: Thanks for that. Fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113262/discussion-between-turo-and-chomp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a big mistake of me, because i didn't know how `Eclipse` handles `String` variables in  debugging mode. `Append` was working perfectly fine, but the String was too large for seeing it, and in a case like this, Eclipse shows the string until a certain point, after that, shows "...".

I selected the value of the `textBuffer` variable in order to change it, for trying to see the real value, and the value was right there, the full String of the file, from the first character to the last.

Huge thanks to @turo for the gigantic effort in helping me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873949/viewing-complete-strings-while-debugging-in-eclipse for more information

Answer (score 0):

Found the constellation, but can't reproduce:

changed the code a bit:

```
        case XMLEvent.CHARACTERS:
            if (isInteresting(elementStack.peek())) {
                int sizeBefore = textBuffer.length();
                String text = reader.getText();
                int textSize = text.length();
                textBuffer.append(text);
                int sizeAfter = textBuffer.length();
                assert sizeBefore + textSize == sizeAfter : "Error occured " + sizeBefore + " " + textSize + " :"
                        + text;
                if (textSize == 1352) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "Size before " + sizeBefore + " textSize " + textSize + " sizeafter " + sizeAfter);
                }
            }
            break;
```

got no AssertionError but the output

```
Parsing pages and extracting links...
Size before 30643 textSize 1352 sizeafter 31995
...........Size before 0 textSize 1352 sizeafter 1352
...Size before 83963 textSize 1352 sizeafter 85315
.
15309 pages parsed in 0 seconds.
```

Comment: It was a newbie error from my side @turo, that originated this problem. Sorry and huge thanks for your help!