# Issue with the String type in Java

Tags: java

I am creating/forming a `query` with any numbers of columns in a loop using java. But all columns are not adding to `String object` after a point all the columns are not adding to a string object, which(String object) suppose to be sent to the `database`.
Here I am pasting last two columns that are added to the string object

```
  String createquery;
    createquery = "CREATE TABLE ";

    createquery += cell.getStringCellValue() + " " + "VARCHAR(50)," 

value of the createquery: Create Table Table-name <many columns added before this>,BV_DXK_GEN_GUUR_AMT_AMT VARCHAR(50),PV_EXR_GEN_INS...
```

The last columns which is added is truncated and added with three dots and the remaining columns are left off adding to query.

The problem looks to be with size of the string, when I checked the createquery size which was exactly 10001 characters after that its adding 3 dots and rest of the columns are are not added
what could be the reason and how to solve it.

Comment: What tool are you using to display the value of createquery?

Comment: can you put the proper output which you are getting, your SQL query shows wrong may be you are not pasing it properly, after table name there should be a paratheses and it should not a comma also

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: no, the three dot is not a problem, you are using eclipse to inspect, that is fine, but your SQL itself is wrong

Comment: Hope you are using eclipse while debugging the code for this scenario
please increase the max length. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873949/viewing-complete-strings-while-debugging-in-eclipse)

Comment: Yes I am uing eclipse

Comment: please increase the max length

Comment: Thank you Sri, I could see now