# JSONArray is not consuming full response from HTTPServletResponse

Tags: json, spring-boot, debugging, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm filtering a response from a Filter in my Spring Boot application.
My requirement is to get the response Body. I'm using below method. But when i was debugging the complete response(JSONArray) as an array is missing. the response looks like  at the end **"crea..."** and last part is missing with "]".

I'm using ContentCachingResponseWrap to cache the response.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
    request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper multiReadResponse =new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    chain.doFilter(request, multiReadResponse);
    InputStream responseInputStream = multiReadResponse.getContentInputStream();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(inputStream));
    multiReadResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
}
```

How I am missing the full response.

Answer (score 1):

IDE shows '...' after a certain number of length. you need to increase it if you want to see the full length. This question was answered here. [Viewing complete strings while debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873949/viewing-complete-strings-while-debugging-in-eclipse)